# Ao aplicar Hover em uma UL, modificar LI e DIV

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="submenu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-xstore"></div>
        <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce">xStore - Plataforma de E-commerce</a>
        <div class="submenuDescription">Tecnologia para a realização de vendas de forma prática, segura e completa.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Eu quero que quando eu passe o mouse no **ul**, ele modifique o background da própria **ul** e também as cores de **a** e da **div** *submenuDescription*. E também o *background-position* de *btn-submenu-xstore*.

Fiz isso daqui, mas não deu certo:

```
.submenu ul:hover {background: #00478d;}
.submenu ul:hover .submenu ul li a {color: #fff;}
.submenu ul:hover .submenuDescription {color: #fff;}
.submenu ul:hover .btn-submenu-xstore {background-position: -50px}
```

O único que funciona é o .submenu ul:hover {background: #00478d;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segunda linha do CSS está incorreta, mas o restante está funcionando. Deve ficar assim:

```
.submenu ul:hover {background: #00478d;}
.submenu ul:hover li a {color: #fff;}
.submenu ul:hover .submenuDescription {color: #fff;}
```

### EDIT

```
.submenu ul:hover .btn-submenu-xstore, 
.submenu ul:hover .btn-submenu-b2b,
.submenu ul:hover .btn-submenu-marketplace {background-position: -50px}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, teria como eu incluir mais duas classes em .submenu ul:hover .btn-submenu-xstore {background-position: -50px} ?

Comment: .btn-submenu-b2b e .btn-submenu-marketplace

Comment: Sim, separe com virgulas. Cheque a edição! :)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: @FelipeStoker De nada! Boa sorte!